# Devise OmniauthsController not being used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I am trying to create a Rails app using Devise with Omniauth options for user management.  I am trying to get one OAuth service working at a time, starting with Github.  The welcome page loads, I click sign in with Github, go to the Github authorization page and allow, then the redirect starts and I get the error message `The action 'github' could not be found for Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController`.

I do not understand why I'm getting this error b/c I have defined the action in app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb as follows:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def github
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    sign_in_and_redirect @user
  end

end
```

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,     :omniauthable, :confirmable, :lockable, :omniauth_providers => [:github]

end
```

and app/config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'
  root 'welcome#index'

  devise_for :users, :controller => { :omniauth => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
end
```

It's trying to fallback to the default Devise OmniauthsCallbacksController instead of using my users/omniauths_callbacks_controller.rb, but I don't know why.  Any suggestions?

Possibly relevant info:

```
ruby v 2.4.0
rails v 50.0.1
omniauth v 1.3.2
devise v 4.2.0
omniauth-github v 1.1.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace

```
devise_for :users, :controller => { :omniauth => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

to

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

Comment: Updated question.  That is the name of the file, earlier had a typo on my part.